# is it possiable to collect portion of cpus and ram of 100 computers and use them for diffrent process centrally

Tags: architecture, cpu, hardware, ram

I have say 800 workstations, i need to accumulate all of the ram and cpu core in one place to use them for different kinda of process,
Say for example i want to use it for rendering in muster.

Is there any software like seti for creating a bank of cpus and ram .

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of accumulating ram and cpu core would imply you want to make a large single image system out of a bunch of workstations.   This sort of thing was widely explored in the 1990s and fell out of fashion in part because it was unable to deal with nodes spontaneously failing.   The same problem applies to modern multi-processors, but at a smaller scale.

If you mean to simply use them as a cluster -- a set of communicating machines to perform a task -- then what you are asking for is very close to what kubernetes (k8s) does.